# Wordpress category base not in post permalink

Tags: permalinks

I have a woocommerce site setup with a blog.

### For the shop:

- example.net/shop (Shows all products)
- example.net/shop/category (Shows all products in the category)
- example.net/shop/category/product (Shows the product)

### For the blog:

- example.net/blog (Shows all posts)
- example.net/blog/category (Shows all posts in the category)
- example.net/blog/category/post (Shows the post)

### My Permalink Settings are:

#### Common Settings

- Custom Structure - /%category%/%postname%

#### Optional

- Category base - blog
- Product category base - shop
- Product tag base - tag

#### Product permalinks

- Custom base - /shop/%product_cat%/

As I said the links are working as I want them to work, when I create a post category I get the url "example.net/blog/category-slug" **but when I create a post and add it to the category the permalink I get is not "example.net/blog/category-slug/post-slug" it's "example.net/category-slug/post-slug"**

By the ways there will be no subcategories used.

Comment: The category base is just for category permalinks and not post permalinks. Hence the name "*category* base". To have the `blog` in the post permalink, you'd need to set the permalink structure to `/blog/%category%/%postname%/`, but that would result in a conflict with the `blog` as the category base.

Comment: Got it working thank you! I had to set the Common > Custom Structure to "/blog/%category%/%postname%" and the category base to "blog/.".

The shop permalinks are unaffected.

Comment: Well yes, that `blog/.` may work in avoiding the conflict, but if I'm not mistaken, that will not work for `/blog/<category-slug>/page/<number>` (e.g. `example.com/blog/uncategorized/page/2`), i.e. *paged* requests for a category.

Comment: @Daviid I tried your suggestion but with "blog/." set to category base now it gives 404 for the category page. I tried exactly the same configuration as you have suggested. Am I missing something? did you make any changes from the backend to make it work?